# On() not attaching handler to dynamically inserted element

Tags: jquery

I call a service that injects a table into a page:

```
$('.lobSelect').click(function (e) {
        e.stopPropagation();
        var yOffset = $(this).position().top + $(this).height() + 'px';
        var xOffset = $(this).position().left + 'px';

        $('<div class="dropdown-wrapper"></div>')
            .css('top', yOffset)
            .css('left', xOffset)
            .html('foo')
            .prependTo('body');

        $.ajax({
            url: 'http://localhost:15485/api/lineofbusiness',
            type: 'get',
            dataType: 'json'
        })
        .done(function (data) {
            var table = '<table class="multi-column-table">'
            data.forEach(function (item) {
                table += '<tr>';
                table += '<td data-target-class="lobSelect">' + item.LOB_Code + '</td>';
                table += '<td data-target-class="">' + item.LOB_Name + '</td>';
                table += '</tr>';
            });
            $('.dropdown-wrapper').html(table);
        })
        .fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            alert(errorThrown);
        });
    });
```

Why is it that this attaches a handler:

```
$('body').on('click', '.multi-column-table tr', function () {
        //do stuff
    });
```

But not this:

```
$('.multi-column-table tr').on('click', function () {
        //do stuff
    });
```

**EDIT**

I had thought that On() allowed you to bind handlers to elements that are injected in future. Is there a better way to do what I'm attempting without using $('body')?

Comment: When the event handler is made, "$('.multi-column-table tr')" doesn't select anything since it is not yet in the DOM. The first one works because "$('body')" is in the DOM at that point. Unless I'm mistaken, this is in the documentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would attach the handler when I add the table.

```
// untested
.done(function (data) {
    var $table = $('<table class="multi-column-table">');
    data.forEach(function (item) {
        var $tr = $('<tr>').appendTo($table);
        var $td = $('<td data-target-class="lobSelect">').text(item.LOB_Code);
        var $td2 = $('<td data-target-class="">').text(item.LOB_Name);
        $tr.append($td);
        $tr.append($td2);
        $tr.on('click', function () {
            // do stuff
        });
    });

    $('.dropdown-wrapper').html($table);
 })
```

As I mentioned in my comment, `$('.multi-column-table tr')` does not work because it is not in the DOM when you set the event handler, but `$('body')` is in the DOM (and works).

Answer (score 0):

The first attaches the handler to 'body', which exists when the handler is attached.  Body will only call the handler if the target matches the selector (.multi-column-table tr).

The second tries to attach the handler to an element that isn't yet in the DOM.

Answer (score 0):

Because `$('.multi-column-table tr')` gives a static list of all the `<tr>` elements that match the selector *at the time you call the selector*. It doesn't get updated as new elements that would match that selector are added to the page.

That's the whole point of using `on()` - you can attach events to *container* elements, and thanks to event bubbling you can listen for events on child/descendent elements, including dynamically added ones.

Answer (score 0):

See first one attaching the event to the `body` which exists before the element which needs the event be attached to.

Second one won't work because that also doesn't exist when event was attached.